# Way to remove string concat in Oracle-db (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-oracledb

Is there a way to prevent string concat in the sql query that might cause sql injection?

The searchParameter and searchString are optional parameters that came from get request. These should add to where clause that will filter the results depending on user input.

Both searchParameter and searchString must not be null in order to complete the statement.

Thank you.

```
async getDetails(searchParameter, searchString, skip = 0, limit = 25, transactionSeq) {

    let filterQuery = "";
    if(searchParameter && searchString)
    {
      filterQuery = "AND " + searchParameter + "=" + "'" + searchString + "'";
    }

    const sql = `
      select * from (
      select /*+first_rows(${limit})*/
      a.record_sequence,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.record_sequence) RN
      from TABLE_NAME a
      WHERE TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE = :t
      ) where RN between :n AND :m ${filterQuery}
      ORDER BY RN 
    `;
    const bindVars = {
      t: transactionSeq,
      n: skip + 1,
      m: skip + limit
    };
    const resultAsync = this._database.simpleExecute(sql, bindVars);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should allow-list any statement text that you using in string concatenation.  I presume `searchParameter` matches a column name so check that the value is a column that exists in the table. Throw an error if it is not known.  See [Binding Column and Table Names in Queries](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#sqlbindtablename).

Then use a bind variable for user data `searchString`.  You can add this to `bindVars`.

Also you might like to use the [newer limit syntax](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#pagingdata):

```
const myoffset = 0;       // do not skip any rows (start at row 1)
const mymaxnumrows = 20;  // get 20 rows

const result = await connection.execute(
  `SELECT last_name
   FROM employees
   ORDER BY last_name
   OFFSET :offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :maxnumrows ROWS ONLY`,
  {offset: myoffset, maxnumrows: mymaxnumrows});
```

Comment: Hi Christopher, Thank you for your answer. I have a question, how to run the same statement if searchParameter and searchString are null, that was used as bind variables?

Comment: Just don't add the extra bind parameter to bindVars.